# Lifetimes in Rust: mut data borrowed

Tags: rust, lifetime

The following code reports an error：
**borrowed value does not live long enough**

```rust
fn main() {
    let e = 100;
    let mut a = (1,);
    let mut b = (&e,);
    {
        let mut c = (&mut a, &mut b);
        let f = &mut c;
        f.1 .0 = &(f.0 .0);
    }
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

But the following code is correct:

```rust
fn main() {
    let e = 100;
    let a = (1,);
    let mut b = (&e,);
    {
        let mut c = (&a, &mut b);
        let f = &mut c;
        f.1 .0 = &(f.0 .0);
    }
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Why?!!

Full error message for the first code:

```
error[E0597]: `c` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:17
   |
6  |         let mut c = (&mut a, &mut b);
   |             ----- binding `c` declared here
7  |         let f = &mut c;
   |                 ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
8  |         f.1 .0 = &f.0 .0;
9  |     }
   |     - `c` dropped here while still borrowed
10 |     println!("{:?}", b);
   |                      - borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76323931/edit) your question to add the full error message (from `cargo check`, not from an IDE). The full error usually contains explanations about _which_ data doesn't live long enough, and why.

Comment: @SvenMarnach At first I thought you are correct, but now I'm not so sure. I believe the difference stems from the fact that shared references are `Copy` while mutable references are not, but I still need to dig deeper to understand.

Comment: Here's a trimmed down example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12448dadf15e554af801812d7f7ca098. You can still remove the `mut` from `c` and it compiles.

Comment: @SvenMarnach What is the difference to the version I gave?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Apparently I reposted your link, so there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because shared references are `Copy`, while mutable references are not.

Here's a trimmed down version of your code, which is easier to discuss:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    let b;
    {
        let mut c = &mut a;
        // Or:
        let mut c = &a;
        let f = &mut c;
        b = &**f;
    }
    println!("{b}");
}
```

Let's call the lifetimes of `a` and `c` `'a` and `'c` respectively. Therefore, `f` has type `&'c mut &'a [mut] i32`. When we do `b = &**f`, there is a difference between the mutable and immutable version.

In the immutable version, we dereference `f` to get `&'a i32`. We then **copy** this reference (which is fine because shared references are `Copy`), and get a freestanding reference of type `&'a i32`. We can assign this reference (or the reborrowed version of it, `&*r`) to `b`, because `a` has the same scope `b` has.

In the mutable case, we also dereference `f`. However, the reference we get is a mutable reference: `&'a mut i32`. Since mutable references are not `Copy`, we cannot copy it to a freestanding reference. It has to stay where it is, behind the `&'c mut` of `f`.

What we can do, however, is to reborrow this reference to create a reference descended from it. However, when you reborrow a reference of type `&'a mut &'b mut T`, you cannot get a reference of type `&'b mut T`, only `&'a mut T`. Otherwise, the reference you got could outlive the original reference, and exist while you have no permission for such reference.

Therefore, we get **`&'c mut i32`**, and not `&'a mut i32`. `b` outlives `c`, so we cannot assign a `&'c mut i32` (or a shared `&'c i32` created from it) to `b`.